# Identify Results tool not previewing fid instead of 'Display Field' in some cases

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, identify, results

When I click on the "Identify Results," some layers of my GeoPackage display the attribute selected under layer properties/Display, but other layers will show the fid instead of the field I've attribute I've selected under layer properties/Display. Any idea why that might be?

Are there certain characters that could throw it off? Or maybe if there is another layer that has a feature with the same value in their respective display attributes?

In the below, the (53) shown from Riser layer is the fid, and not the "Name", but the others are all working as expected.

[image]